# Strange outcome from string comparison in jsp scriptlet

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I have this code in my .jsp file:

```
<%= formBean.getMonth() == "default" %>
```

I print the value first to make sure it equals to "default":

```
<%= formBean.getMonth() %>
```

and it does, but when I compare it to "default" as I do above it prints false. I am puzzled what
could the problem be.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you are maintaining other developer's code, stay away from scriptlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `equals()` method to compare the String values as below::

```
   <%= formBean.getMonth().equals("default") %>
```

`==` will compare the object instances **and return false in your case as the String object instances are not the same**.

Comment: I did, I also wanted to give you point, but i need 15 reputation :)